# Is there an easier way to sort a response object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

At the moment I'm using the following to sort `TypeCode` (string) in a response object.

This seems a little over kill. Is there an easier way to achieve this with one for each loop?

```
if (response && response.length > 0) {
    var sortedArray = [];
    $.each(response, function (i, dict) {
        sortedArray.push(dict.TypeCode);
    });
    sortedArray.sort();
    $.each(sortedArray, function (i, dict) {
        console.log(dict);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed `TypeCode` was a number. You can pas a `compareFunction` to [**`sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
var sortedResponse = response.sort(function (d1, d2) {
    return d1.TypeCode - d2.TypeCode;
});
```

If `TypeCode` is a string then:

```
var sortedResponse = response.sort(function (d1, d2) {
    var type1 = d1.TypeCode, type2 = d2.TypeCode;

    return type1 < type2? -1 : +(type1 > type2);
});
```

Comment: Apologies, `TypeCode` is a string.

Comment: What if I wanted to order by `TypeCode` desc or asc?

Comment: @gotnull Well you can just inverse the conditions. Basically, if `type1` is smaller than `type2`, we return `-1`, if it's the opposite we return `1` and if both are equal we return `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the original `response` array, by providing a comparison function that compares the `TypeCode` properties of each element.

```
response.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.TypeCode - b.TypeCode
});
$.each(response, function(i, dict) {
    console.log(dict.TypeCode);
});
```